# Access to node based on taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

In Drupal 7 I'm trying to hide a node from a listing view based on whether the current user has a certain role **and** the node references a child term of a specific taxonomy term.

For example I have a node with content type 'job' and I want users with the role 'Store Manager' to be able to see all jobs except those that have a taxonomy term with the parent 'Manager'.

Comment: Is this listing created using views?

Comment: Sorry - yes it is!